# Migrating to Twitter API version 1.1 (?)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am quite new to Twitter API.
I don't know what is wrong with this code, it should work OK according to tweepy documentation:

```
import oauth, tweepy 
from time import sleep

#stars is confident information
username = "*******"
password = "***********"
auth = tweepy.BasicAuthHandler(username, password)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

api.update_status('hello from tweepy!')
```

Terminal is showing me this:

```
$ python py/twi.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py/twi.py", line 11, in <module>
    api.update_status('hello from tweepy!')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 179, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 162, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to     API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.', 'code': 68}]
```

Please help.

Comment: You are using Twitter API 1.0 which is no longer in use.

Comment: Have you updated tweepy in a while? In a quick glance at github, it looks like it's updated.

Comment: I writed `sudo apt-get install python-tweepy` in terminal, nothing new.

Comment: There is no documentation for updated Tweepy :(

Comment: How to fix this code to make it valid for version 1.1?

Answer (score 2):

You should install `tweepy` directly from the github:

```
git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
cd tweepy
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to list this change in a `requirements.txt` file for pip, you can replace

`tweepy==2.0`

with

`-e git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git#egg=tweepy`